# How will the Imputers work if all the values in a column is missing in input vector in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, training-data, imputation

I have a dataset with large number of columns, I have programmed my application in such a way that if any value for the given columns is missing then it would filled with imputer values with mean as the imputer strategy.

However, I am bit concerned that if all the values of the entire column is missing then how would the imputer perform, and what would be the right approach in such a case?

Answer (score 1):

If in a given column, all data is missing, then the Imputer will discard that column.

Here is an example, with 4 samples and 2 columns, with one sample having a missing value:

```
X = np.array([[1,1],[1,2],[1,1],[1,2],[1,np.nan]])
imputer = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)
print(imputer.fit_transform(X))
```

This prints out

```
 [[ 1.   1. ]
 [ 1.   2. ]
 [ 1.   1. ]
 [ 1.   2. ]
 [ 1.   1.5]]
```

However, if all data in the second column is missing:

```
X = np.array([[1,np.nan],[1,np.nan],[1,np.nan],[1,np.nan],[1,np.nan]])
imputer = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)
print(imputer.fit_transform(X))
```

We obtain:

```
[[ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]]
```

This default behaviour could be the right approach in that case, because this colums (*i.e* this feature) cannot be used anyway.

Comment: How would then the input vector of prediction be. ? If suppose the new input vector has value for that particular value the will the model work?

Comment: I think it depends on multiple things here :
- If your new input vector is to be used in the training set, you could either consider that this one value for this given column is not useful, and also discard it, or you could use the imputer on the original dataset to impute the values for this given column for the rest of the vectors (an hazardous approach if you only have one value in this column for the whole dataset)
- If your new input vector is in the test set, the model would not have been trained using values for this specific feature, and it would be necessary to remove this column.